# Запуск эмулятора в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Возникли проблемы с запуском эмулятора в *Android Studio*. Выдает вот эту ошибку:

> emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file!!
>
> emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is undefined

В чем проблемы, хотя не так давно все работало

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: А почему бы вам не использовать [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) он куда быстрее и менее глюкав.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно ему не хватает каких-то системных образов.
Например: `ARM EABI v7a System Image` для той `API`, который(-ое) используется для запуска эмулятора.
Проверь, чтобы папка по пути `$ANDROID_HOME/system-images/android-<YOUR DESIRED API>/armeabi-v7a` существует и не пуста. В противном случае установи/переустанови недостающие изображения через `SDK Manager`.

Comment: `System Image` - это не *системмная картинка*. Это образ системы.

Comment: @metalurgus, хм, в документации не пишется, что это образ системы. Может это имеется в виду, но об этом явно не сказано.

Comment: Конечно об этом не сказано. Документации на рус. языке нет, а переводится `system image` как `образ системы` https://translate.google.com/#en/ru/system%20image

Comment: @metalurgus, тогда ясно